# How can I find out who is sharing a URL via FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to know who is sharing http://portuguese-american-journal.com/advertising/ via FQL.

Current the share count reads: `Share count: 7`

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** know *who* is sharing a link. Facebook won't share that info with you.

Comment: what infor can I get? Can I get the comment context if a user is  ommenting on a url?

Comment: Commenting..like in the news feed? no you can't. You can get the numbers of shares, likes...etc. Check [`link_stat`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)